If $R/\langle r\rangle\cong k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$, does this implies that $R\cong k[x_1,\dots, x_n,x_{n+1}]$?
Let $R$ be an algebra over a field $k$, and let $r\in R$ be an element such that the quotient of $R$ with the ideal generated by $r$ is a polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $k$, and so that the map $\phi_r:R\rightarrow R$ given by $a\mapsto a\cdot r$ is injective.
Does it follow that $R\cong k[x_1,\dots, x_n,x_{n+1}]$?
I feel like the answer should be yes because I cannot think of a counter example to save my life, but I cannot prove it.

Perhaps it would help you to look at the case where $n = 0$ first.

That would imply the existence of a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ generated by a single element in a $k$ algebra $R$ such that $R/\mathfrak m\cong \mathbb k$?

Consider the localization $k[x]_{(x)}$ this has only one nonzero prime ideal so it's definitely not isomorphic to $k[x]$ which has infinitely many prime ideals. Note that we have $k[x]_{(x)}/(x) \cong k$. As this is a domain, the multiplication by $x$ map is injective.
